# Couchbase Sync Function - How can I get all users who have access to a channel within the sync function

Tags: synchronization, couchbase, gateway

I would like to get all the user ID’s that have access to a channel from the sync gateway. For example, if I grant two different users access to a channel. Then a new document comes in that would be assigned to that channel, I would like to get the array of users that have access to that channel first.

I need the array of users who have access to that channel so that I can send out an APNS (apples push notification) to the users of that channel when a document arrives that will be added to that channel.

Ideally, it would be nice if I could just do

```
{
   var usr_arr = channel(the_channel).users();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This capability doesn't currently exist in Sync Gateway (as of version 2.0).

You can map users to channels, so the way I solved this (also for use with push notifications) was to build the inverse map by scanning through users and getting the channels they have access to.  Then I keep that up-to-date by processing the Sync Gateway changes feed.  Look for record ids that start with `_user/`.

This serves a double purpose in that I also listen to the changes feed for mutations to documents with a channel designation.  I then push a notification to the users with access to that channel to run a replication, instead of having replications always on.